# Extending express.Request in project

Tags: typescript, express

I am new to Typescript, so bear with me.

I am working on an Express-based web service. I want to let a piece of early middleware set a logging object on the request object, and use it later in the request handler flow.

The middleware and the final request handler are organized in different files.

What would be the best way to centrally extend the express.Request-object to allow using this logging object without having type warnings?

Just to show what I have and want:

The file that instantiates express and sets my log object:

```
const app = express();
const log = console;

app.use((req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
    req.log = log;
    next();
});
```

A request handler:

```
(req: express.Request, res: express.Response): void => {
    req.log("request was made");
    res.send();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can extend the `express.Request` object like this:

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      log(...params: any[]): void
    }
  }
}
```

Or, if you want to make a clearer distinction between the vanilla `Request` type and your augmented version, you could do something like this:

```
interface RequestWithLogging extends express.Request {
  log(...params: any[]): void
}

app.get('/', (req: RequestWithLogging, res: express.Response) => {
  req.log('Log something')
  res.send('Hello World!')
})
```

Comment: That's awesome! And it can go in a separate .d.ts-file in my project, so it doesn't pollute anywhere.

Ill test this out for awhile and see if there are any pitfalls. :)

Comment: And how do I change t he name?